# Add groups permission on folder/item using APIs?

Tags: api, cloudbees

I am trying to do some automations to add/delete/modify group permissions on a folder. I tried to check this using REST APIs but I did not find an option to do this. 
Are there other APIs that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about role-based access control in Jenkins Enterprise? If so, see the [documentation on using CLI](http://jenkins-enterprise.cloudbees.com/docs/user-guide-docs/rbac-sect-script.html).